# Light Modulation and Detection

Tags: arduino, communication, infrared, uv

IR light is the mainstay frequency for optical communication systems.
How could I experiment with UV frequencies doing the same thing?
Ideally I want to set up a serial link just as is often done with IR.

Thanks you all for your help on this matter.

Answer (score 4):

Surely a UV light bright enough to be of practical use would also be quite dangerous to the naked eye?

That said, perhaps a UV laser could be dropped into something like this:
http://www.ohmpie.com/laserModem

Comment: You are correct, using a UV light source in this method will be dangerous. The darker the room, the better it works, the worse off your eye is for exposure.

Comment: heck, even IR lasers can be more dangerous in the dark, b/c your pupil is more dilated.

Comment: All Lasers are more dangerous in the dark. I did not mean to imply anything different from that. High brightness IR LEDs are in general not a major concern. High Brightness UV light is. It does not need to be a laser to cause permanent eye damage. Just the one I have in the darkroom at school can make you rub your eyes for ours.

Answer (score 4):

I actually did some research a couple months ago for a project that involved semiconductors with band gaps in the range needed for UV LEDs.

You can find near UV LEDs commercially available in the 380-400nm range.  This is like a "black light" area, you can even find UV flash lights that operate in this range.  You could use these LEDs, you'd have to build your own receiver as i'm pretty sure there are no commercial options.  You can probably follow a schematic for an IR receiver but will have to make adjustments for the high forward voltage drops of the diodes that produce this type of light, 3-4V.

Keep in mind that UV light is easily absorbed by most everyday materials.  I don't think you'll get nearly the range you get from IR.

There are semiconductors that can produce UV light as low as ~225nm as i recall there are a couple companies working on this tech, [Crystal IS](http://www.crystal-is.com/) is the one i remember doing it for use to kill bacteria in water.  I don't think any of the companies working on it are in commercial development yet.

As to the eye damage issue, UVB and UVC are the real damaging ones to skin, well all DNA, but thats in the < 315nm range for which he probably won't find a commerical source for light in this range.  **EDIT: I'm clearly not a doctor so please don't take this to mean you shouldn't research this more and take proper safety precautions, this is just as i understand it.**

Comment: The oxygen in the air starts to attenuate strongly as you dip below 300nm, so range would be very limited at that wavelength. But that stuff is Extremely Dangerous anyway.